# Transfer not showing up on either Etherscan or Metamask wallet Despite reflecting in Metamask balance

Tags: ether, metamask, coinbase

As I was going back through my (very few) Ethereum transactions, I noticed something odd... I transferred ETH twice from Coinbase to Metamask, but only one of the transfers is showing up on Metamask / through Etherscan. Doubly weird is that the balance in my Metamask obviously shows that both went through (the one transaction wouldn't have been able to fund the balance after the purchase of an ETH NFT!).

Any clue what is going on here and why the second transfer to Metamask isn't captured by Metamask or Etherscan, and yet my Metamask ETH balance is still acting as if the transfer successfully went through? The three transactions pictured on Metamask below are the ONLY transactions that show up for this wallet.

[image: Coinbase export screenshot]

[image: metamask screenshot]

Comment: Can you share your wallet address